# How To Deal With Datebase Size?

Tags: 7, database

I'm using the *Domain Access* module to share the same database with six different sub-domains. My concern is the database limit which is set to 1000 MB.

Is there a way to create new a database once the previous one reached  700 MB?

Comment: I think limit the database to 700MB is not a good idea, instead I would think to split your subdomains in separate Drupal installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use  the [Memcache API and Integration](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) module or the [APC - Alternative PHP Cache](http://drupal.org/project/apc) module to store session and cache data
- Use a log back-end that doesn't store data in the database
- Don't store logs too long, if you have to keep them in the database.

If the above fails, just change your hosting company or hosting plan, to get bigger limit. Database space is cheap, nowadays.

Comment: Molot will boost module do that thing or not ?

Comment: @Bala nope, Boost provides only a HTML copy of your site for faster serving of static content. It does not prevent logs from being created, nor does it prevent sessions - if they happen, they happen, boost or not. It may help a bit with anonymous user sessions if they are initiated on pages that should be static (and are not excluded from cache in Boost config), but that's all.